# Laravel whereHas when connecting foreign key is not null then apply where

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

This is my query using eloquent `with` and `whereHas` functions.

```
$list = $list->with([
    'site' => function($query) {
        $query->select('site_id', 'name')->where('status', 1);
    },
    'certification' => function($query) {
        $query->select('certification_id', 'name')->where('status', 1);
    },
])->whereHas('site', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
})
->whereHas('certification', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
});
->where('status', '1')
```

Certification and site have Many to One relation with list table.

However, the above code would work fine till all the items in list table has a `certification_id`. But at times `certification_id` can be `Null`.

How do I write this query so as to implement `whereHas` only when certification_id is not null. So as to give all the results `where certification_id is Null` + give all the results where `certification_id is not null and certifications.status = 1`

Relation in list table is as

```
public function certification()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Certification', 'certification_id', 'certification_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasted 4 hours and it clicked as I posted this question. I nested the `whereHas` or `certification_id is null` in a `where` block and tada!

```
$list = $list->with([
    'site' => function($query) {
        $query->select('site_id', 'name')->where('status', 1);
    },
    'certification' => function($query) {
        $query->select('certification_id', 'name')->where('status', 1);
    }
])->whereHas('site', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
})
->where(function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('certification', function($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1);
    })->orWhereNull('certification_id');
})
```